# Need to show file icons instead of just link in html

Tags: php, html

I have the file upload function using php and then I need to provide the links for those files to download them. Presently I have just given a hyperlink eg :

```
<a href="/files/testbook.pdf"> Text Book </a>
```

But this just shows up a link.. instead need to display a pdf file icon. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the IMG tag?

Comment: I think you need to learn more about HTML.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jocelyn says in the comments, you need to use the tag img to display an image:

```
<a href="/files/testbook.pdf"><img src="/path/to_your_image.png" alt="Text Book"/> Text Book </a>
```

I recommend you to check the type of the file and then put the correct image (PDF, ZIP, DOC ...), you can do this using:

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, 'YOUR_FILENAME');
```

And then do a switch or an if..else based on your allowed mime types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a css selector to select all links to pdf files and apply icons dynamically. This means you dont need to add seperate `img` tags to all your links. And you can add other selectors for different file types, or for external vs internal links etc..

An example would be as follows in your CSS..

```
a[href$='.pdf'] {    
    display:inline-block;    
    line-height:18px; /* check your icon height */    
    padding-right:20px;    
    background: transparent url(images/pdf.png)  center right no-repeat;    
}     
/* change padding-right to padding left and background 
position center right to center left 
if you want  to display icon on the left side */
```

This useful code was taken from http://www.vision.to/add-a-small-icon-to-your-links-css-only.php

And an interesting read on the topic here http://www.portent.com/blog/design-dev/class-up-your-link-icons-with.htm

Answer (score 0):

Search online for a PDF icon, download it then

```
<a href=file.pdf><img src=pdficon.jpg> test book</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
<a href="/files/testbook.pdf"> <img src="path_to_image" alt="Textbook"/> </a>
```

It displays the image as the link. When you click the image the browser will start the download for the PDF or display the PDF in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it better with CSS. 
I'd also recommend using the target attribute to force the link to open in a new tab, that way site visitors don't navigate away from your site when clicking external links (External for all intents and purposes in this case...)

```
<a id="pdf-link" target="_BLANK" href="/files/testbook.pdf"> Text Book </a>

a#pdf-link {
    background: url('../images/pdf-icon.png') left center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    min-height: <USE-IMAGE-HEIGHT>px;
    padding-left: <USE-IMAGE-WIDTH-PLUS10/20>px;
}
```